# How to close a Node.js UDP (dgram) socket

Tags: node.js, udp

The App crashes if I do not call `client.close` in the program below.

The send of `message` and receiving of `data` works fine. But if I exit the function and comes back to it again later, the App crashes and I can not receive message anymore. I restart the Smart Phone and it works again only for the first time the function runs.

If I put `client.close()` inside the `client.on('message',`, I only get the first data from the host or source, because the socket will close prematurely. Also the App do not crash.
If I remove the `client.close()`, I get all the data from multiple sources saved in the array I provided `let RawMessageUDP = []`.

Also I confirmed that the callback function of the `client.on('message',` will not be executed when there are no more message in the socket.
How can I determine that there are no more message in the socket, so I can close it?

There are two hosts which receives the `message` and reply `data` string back to this App. There are no issues in the host I confirmed since they close the connection after sending.

```
    Send_UDP_Multicast = async () => {
        const message = Buffer.from('Some bytes'); 
        const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

        let RawMessageUDP = []
        let countMessage = 0

        client.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err.stack)
            client.close()
        })

        client.on('message', (data, rinfo) => { //Console: socket-x, bound to address: 0.0.0.0, port: 65000 max

            RawMessageUDP[countMessage] = data.toString()
            console.log('Receiving remote data.' + RawMessageUDP[countMessage])
            countMessage++

            //client.close()
        })

        client.send(message, 0, message.length, 1900, '239.255.255.250', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                client.close();
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/jurniores/SocketUDP resolve your problem. This lib you will find how to disconnect the clients and if the clients fall down it will disconnect them and will not overload your server.

Comment: Hi, the library that you shared might be better shared as a code snippet of the implementation that actually solves the issue with references to the author/library. The library in its current state isn't well suited to be used by other people - it is not included in a package manager repository, and it is hardcoded to always work on the same port which could cause issues for a lot of users